# MERN-Stack Heroku - Cannot GET /

Tags: github, heroku, web-deployment, mern, mongodb-atlas

Trying to get a MERN-Stack to Deploy on Heroku I've added MONGOBD_URI as a key in Config Vars on Heroku and added the MongoDB Atlas value.

Heroku is connected directly to the Github repo and not through the Heroku CLI. I have it set to auto-deploy but recently redeployed it manually.

This was the **Heroku Build Log:**

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.20.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.8
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > nodemon@2.0.6 postinstall /tmp/build_b41198ca_/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       added 290 packages in 6.983s
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 1 package and audited 289 packages in 2.051s
       
       17 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 33M
-----> Launching...
       Released v17
       https://jms-r0b.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

The **browser(Chrome)** only renders `Cannot GET /` and **consol.log()'s** `GET https://jms-r0b.herokuapp.com/ 404 (Not Found) jms-r0b.herokuapp.com/:1`

This is the [LINK](https://github.com/WasteOfADrumBum/r0b) to my repo.

Here's how my **server.js** is setup:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const todoRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

let Todo = require("./models/todo.model");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Express data parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/todos";
mongoose.connect(
  URI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

todoRoutes.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  Todo.find((err, todos) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(todos);
    }
  });
});

todoRoutes.route("/:id").get((req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Todo.findById(id, (err, todo) => {
    res.json(todo);
  });
});

todoRoutes.route("/update/:id").post((req, res) => {
  Todo.findById(req.params.id, (err, todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    } else {
      todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
      todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
      todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
      todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;

      todo
        .save()
        .then((todo) => {
          res.json("Todo updated!");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
        });
    }
  });
});

todoRoutes.route("/add").post((req, res) => {
  let todo = new Todo(req.body);
  todo
    .save()
    .then((todo) => {
      res.status(200).json({ todo: "todo added successfully" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).send("adding new todo failed");
    });
});

todoRoutes.route("/delete/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  Todo.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        msg: todo,
      });
    }
  });
});

app.use("/todos", todoRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("http://localhost:" + PORT);
  console.log(".env.PORT:" + process.env.PORT);
});
```

and this is how my **root package.json** looks:

```
{
  "name": "rob",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "cd client && npm start",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "start": "concurrently \"node server/server.js\" \"npm run client\"",
    "dev": "concurrently \"nodemon server/server.js\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/WasteOfADrumBum/r0b.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/WasteOfADrumBum/r0b/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/WasteOfADrumBum/r0b#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.0.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "ini": "^2.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.5.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "validator": "^12.0.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

I could use a little help. I've deployed 5 other MERN-Stacks with a MongoDB Atlas or JawsDB connection with little to no issues and this one is just throwing me for a loop.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone does things differently, but I think the error is in your connection to MongDB- are you establishing a connection OK or no?

If no connection - You said "I've added MONGOBD_URI as a key in Config Vars on Heroku and added the MongoDB Atlas value."  But I see that "config Vars" is not used in your code- you used the .env as you should to keep your connection password secure...so may just need to add your connection URI to the .env file, and you are good to go?

If your connection is fine, then I would look to your server and suggest to test if the problem is solved using the standard routing:

```
 app.route("/")
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/views/index.html");
    })
```

Comment: It's been establishing the connection. I have added MONGOBD_URI as a key in Config Vars on Heroku and added the MongoDB Atlas value as well. 

I'll give the routing a go and see what comes up.

Comment: Ya sounds like server routing...since all your routes are in the one file(I usually separate out the API routes that need MongoDB), it's easier to just use the simple app.route and should be sweet?